# javascript function call

Tags: javascript

I have popup window which contains a preview button, on clicking it displays the preview of the document selected by the user. This pop up window is called from another page, *fileretension.aspx*. After preview, when the user clicks the close icon of popup window, it calls a function, `DeleteTempFiles`, on the parent page with the filename as the argument.  This is the line of code:

```
window.opener.callBack("DeleteTempFiles('"+fileName+"');");
```

I stored the file name in a hidden variable in the popup window and got the value of `fileName` correctly, but JavaScript throws an error - *"Object doesn't support this property or method"*.

What could be the problem here, is this related to browser?  I used the same function in another page and it woks properly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make up that callBack method? Never seen anyone try to do something like that.

To call a function on the parent window, all you need to do is

```
window.opener.DeleteTempFiles(fileName);
```